# indentation errors in main function for connect four in python

Tags: python

A few minutes ago my program was fine until I tried adding in a way to make the user be asked to play again. When I put in the loop and indented everything, something got messed up really bad when I took out this part since it didn't work. Now I cant fix the indentation and nothing will work correctly. Can anyone see obvious problems?

```
def main():
     lastRow = 0
     won = 0
     draw = False
     player1turn = True
     print("Welcome to Connect Four!")
     rows = input("Please enter a number of rows: ")
     check = True
     while check == True:
          try:
               if int(rows) <= 4:
                    while int(rows) <= 4:
                         rows = input("Please enter a Valid choice: ")
                    else:
                         check = False
          except ValueError:
               rows = input("Please enter a Valid choice: ")
     columns = input("Please enter a number of columns: ")
     check2 = True
     while check2 == True:
          try:
               if int(columns) <= 4:
                    while int(columns) <= 4:
                         columns = input("Please enter a Valid choice: ")
                    else:
                         check2 = False
          except ValueError:
               columns = input("Please enter a Valid choice: ")
     myBoard = []
     myBoardTemp = []
     for i in range(int(columns)):
          myBoardTemp.append(0)
          for i in range(int(rows)):
               myBoard.append([0] * int(columns))
     printBoard(myBoard)
     check3 = True
     while won == 0 and draw == False:
          move = input("Please enter a move: ")
          while check3 == True:
  try:
                    if int(move) < 0 or int(move) > len(myBoard[0]):
                         while int(move) < 0 or int(move) > len(myBoard[0]):
                              move = input("Please enter a valid choice: ")
                         else:
                              check3 = False
               except ValueError:
                    move = input("Please enter a valid choice: ")
     myBoard, player1turn, lastRow = move2(myBoard,int(move) - 1,player1turn)
     printBoard(myBoard)
     won = checkWin(myBoard,int(move) - 1, lastRow)
     draw = isDraw(myBoard, won)
     if won == 1:
          print("Player 1 has won!")
     elif won == -1:
          print("Player 2 has won!")
     elif draw == True:
          print("It is a draw!")
```

Comment: the outlier `try:` is kind of ovbious ...

Answer (score 0):

The line after `while check3 == True:` is not indented correctly

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico: The question was "where is the trivial error after code modification and reindentation?" My answer: it is there and there. How exactly doesn't it answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

The `try` after `while check3 == True:` isn't properly indented, although I can't tell if that is a transcription error or was in your original code.